# Aurora Serverless (Postgresql) - execute statement timeout 502

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, aws-aurora-serverless

I am building a lambda api connecting to AWS Aurora Serverless Postgres.

- Follow AWS instruction to setup an Aurora Serverless with Postgres compatible (for MySql but still useful for Postgres): https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/configure-connect-serverless-mysql-database-aurora/
- I added port 5432 in inbound of security group

  [image]
- I also use data-api-client to query the database (https://github.com/jeremydaly/data-api-client)
- Built API lambda in Serverless Framework, set `timeout` is 1 min, added role `AmazonRDSDataFullAccess`

My lambda code (built in Serverless framework) is simple:

```
async function query_db(_sql) {
    const data = require('data-api-client')({
      secretArn: constants.DBSecretsStoreArn,
      resourceArn: constants.DBAuroraClusterArn,
      database: constants.DatabaseName
    });

    try {
      let result = await data.query(_sql);
      return result.records;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Lambda :: query_db :: Error: ' + error);
      return error;
    }
  }

  async function run() {

    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 10';
    let result = await query_db(sql);
    console.log('result: '+ JSON.stringify(result));

    return callback(null, {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({msg: 'done})
      });  
  }
```

Result:

- It ran successfully in local (serverless-offline)
- After deploying, it ran timeout, returned 502, error: "Internal server error"

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-api-client` doesn't officially support Postgres, yet.

https://github.com/jeremydaly/data-api-client/issues/27

Comment: I also tested this with Aurora MySQL, it returns the same issue. After 29 secs, it's timeout.

Comment: If it's running successfully locally, but not deployed, it may be a permissions problem. The IAM user you are using locally may have more permissions than the user / role you have setup for your lambda functions. So, I would check for differences between your local IAM user and the role assigned to your lambdas. Also, this is pretty basic, but you need to ensure you have the Data API enabled in RDS for your Aurora Serverless cluster.

Comment: I just deployed several new lambdas using the `data-api-client` and everything is working. It's definitely something with your setup / config.